# How to add a border to an UIImageView located on the LaunchScreen?

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiimage, border, launch-screen

How can I add a border to an UIImageView which is located on the LaunchScreen of an iOS App?

I already tried to do it programmatically and to add user defined runtime attributes (which is not allowed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot *programmatically* do this, however...

If you add an actual border to your bitmap image, the border will get "pixel-stretched" for different screen resolutions.

Another option (which would avoid that issue): You could add a `UIView`, set its background color to the color you want for your border, and add your `UIImageView` as a subview, with constraints set to 1 or 2 points to give it the desired "border width".

Answer (score 1):

LaunchScreen is static so you can't add a border to an `UIImageView` which is located on the LaunchScreen.

An easy and possible way is you have to create an image with border you want and set it inside a normal `UIImageView`. Use auto layout to scale the image if needed.